# Hide the blue user location on mapView

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, swift4, mapkitannotation

I'm trying to hide the blue dot of the user location in my Swift 4 app. I have attempted to turn it off in the storyboard but this doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: Could you share some code of what you have implemented?

Answer (score 2):

You should set the `showUsersLocation` to `false` on your `MKMapView`.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1452682-showsuserlocation